# Clickable dojo labels

Tags: javascript, dojo

If you're using dojo form inputs and want to have labels for them like that:

```
<label for="???">Email</label>
<input
  type="text"
  name="email"
  dojoAttachPoint="email"
  dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox"
/>
```

the label is not clickable, because there is no way of knowing the id of the input before it's rendered.

Does there exist a solution for this other than hacking an id in that dojo generates for that element?

**UPDATE**

It's actually even more difficult than I thought, because the input field in dojo gets rendered as

```
<div class="dijit dijitTextBox" id="widget_dijit_form_TextBox_0">
  <input class="dijitReset dijitInputField" value="Χ" type="text" tabindex="-1">
  ...
</div>
```

and the underlying input field doesn't have an id

Answer (score 1):

Did you try giving an id to the input?

```
<label for="myIdComesHere">Email</label>
<input
  id="myIdComesHere"
  type="text"
  name="email"
  dojoAttachPoint="email"
  dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox"
/>
```

---

If I recall correctly, this id can be used both by dojo.byId (to fetch the domNode aka the input tag) and by dijit.byId (to fetch the dijit Widget instance)

Comment: This solution works only for simple cases. Imagine having a widget with this label and input in the template. Now if you want to place several copies of this same widget on the same page you'll be in trouble if you use ids. You generally avoid using id and use dojoAttachPoint instead to reference that particular instance of the element from JS. Basically it seems like dijit.form.Label is missing from the library that could be attached using dojoAttachPoint rather than id, which means it's probably time to write a dojox.form.Label ;)

Comment: Well, "hacking in the id dojo generates" isn't that bad then :P

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating the form inside of a widget, you can use `this.id` to get the id of that instance of the widget.

If your widget is called `my.form`, the ID of the widget will be `my_form_0` and will increment for each new form widget created.

To create a unique ID for your form elements, use

```
var id = this.id + '_email';

'<label for="' + id + '"/>'
'<input type="text" id="' + id + '"/>'
```

That will give you

```
<label for="my_form_0_email"/>
<input type="text" id="my_form_0_email"/>
```

If you're creating the input using the dijit.form.TextBox, that textbox will ALWAYS have a unique ID on your page. The actual `<input>` dom element inside the widget will have the ID that's found by grabbing the ID of the widget.

If you create the TextBox programatically, you can do the following:

```
var tb = new dijit.form.TextBox(),
    label = dojo.create("label", {for: tb.id});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about compatibility with IE, you can place the input inside the label:

```
<label><input type=checkbox>hello</label>
```

Comment: An astute observation. Lets leave that as an exercise for the reader, shall we? `<label>name:<input type=text></label>`'

Comment: Coming across the same issue as the OP. This seems like a simple option. The only drawback is that it becomes harder to style to certain visual designs this way. In those cases moonsspoon seems to have a better approach. +1 for a simply use case solution though

Answer (score 1):

As Brian Mathews says the trick is use the id of the widget, but is not necessary do it in javascript, you can do when declaring the widget template

```
<label for="${id}_email"/>
<input type="text" id="${id}_email"/>
```